# Windows 7 strange networking issue

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, home-networking

I got 2 laptops with Windows 7.

- They are located at the same wifi network which consists of only 2
  PC's.
- Workgroups are same, PC names are different.
- Both of them using Kaspersky Internet Security 2013
- Both of them using "Home" networking prfoile.

  Well, it must be allright theoretically but they don't see each other in network.
  I tried to create home group in one of them. Second pc doesn't see this group also.

What else can be issue? I tried all possible issue sources, none of them gave me positive result. Any suggestions?

Comment: First step: can they successfully ping each other?  Second step: what happens if you temporarily disable your firewall/Kaspersky?

Comment: @kmort I haven't tried to ping but when I try to enter \\<second_cpc_name> on explorer, nothing found

Comment: @Tural, please start with a ping by IP address, and then by PC name. if both work, then the issue is with your sharing configuration (homegroup perhaps?), but the pings will tell us whether its a IP/firewall problem, or a name resolution problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on Network Discovery on both machines.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/enable-or-disable-network-discovery

> "Network discovery is a network setting that affects whether your
>   computer can see (find) other computers and devices on the network and
>   whether other computers on the network can see your computer. By
>   default, Windows Firewall blocks network discovery, but you can enable
>   it."

Also, here is an exact how-to of setting up and using a homegroup:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/why-can-t-i-join-a-homegroup

Comment: Discovery is active on both pcs

Comment: Did you follow the directions in the second link?

Comment: Links are broken 11/9/19

Comment: @glenviewjeff Windows 7 is no longer supported.

Comment: Extended support doesn't end until January. Why does that matter? You could link to them via wayback machine.